# Difference between 2 floats

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

How to get a "distance" between two floats?
`Mathf.Abs(X - Y)` will only work correctly if they are both on the same side of zero.
For example:

- `Mathf.Abs(100 - 140)` = 40,
- `Mathf.Abs(40 - 120)` = 80,
- `Mathf.Abs(-120 - (-130)` = 10,
- `Mathf.Abs(-100 - 110)` = 210 ... it doesn't work when one of these floats is below and another is above zero.

This seems like a very common problem, is there some elegant solution for this without resorting to a bunch of if statements?

Comment: missing one `)` in `Mathf.Abs(-120 - (-130) = 10,`

Comment: But distance between `-100` and `110` is 210 - why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is correct. Try to visualize it:

[image]

Distance between `-110` and `100` is the sum of distance between `-110` and `0` (`Mathf.Abs(-110 - 0) = 110`) and distance between `100` and `0` (`Mathf.Abs(100 - 0) = 100`). That is: `110` + `100` = `210`. Perhaps you have a different operation in mind? If you want distance between absolute values of arguments, then try:

```
Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Abs(X) - Mathf.Abs(Y))
```

which will yield `10` for `-110` and `100`.

Comment: These are also handy to remember: `-x - y = -(x+y); x - (-y) = x + y; -x + y = y - x`.

Comment: Thanks for a veeery comprehensive answer even with a picture. It's got to be something completely different in my code than. I've got a camera orbiting around a point and it has irregular movement at -180 to 180 degree transition because of smoothing. It looks choppy without smoothing. This "distance" was supposed to catch this situation and alleviate it, yet it doesn't. Had probably convinced myself that black is white in an inquisitorial pursuit of a culprit that ruins my plans.